# Windows Task Scheduler - Last Run Time and Last Run Result

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

We have several scheduled jobs running in our various servers. I was looking if I could do something to see all the scheduled tasks along with the last run time and the last run result.

I have looked at this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21418/Scheduled-Tasks-Web-Service) but I couldn't find anything for the last run details.

Also, I have looked at the XML file located at

```
C:\Windows\System32\Tasks
```

Using this file I can get the jobs but not the last run details.

I would like to know how I should proceed to get the jobs along with their last run details from remote computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try the managed wrapper for the scheduler API: http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Project is migrated to https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I got it working using the dll they had.

Answer (score 2):

From this 2015 [blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/01/12/use-powershell-to-show-results-of-scheduled-tasks/), you can get this data running this PowerShell command:

```
Get-ScheduledTask | where state -EQ 'ready' | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\scheduledTasksResults.csv
```

The result will be on a CSV file, which you can open with Excel and export it as the bellow table:

```
LastRunTime    | LastTaskResult | NextRunTime | ...
21-12-17 20:24 | 0              | 0           | ...
15-05-18       | 12:55          | 0           | ...
14-05-18 19:13 | 0              | 0           | ...
14-05-18       | 19:14          | 0           | ...
30-11-99 01:00 | 267011         | 0           | ...
15-05-18 12:25 | 0              | 16-05-18    | ...
14-05-18 19:13 | 2147500037     | 0           | ...
15-05-18       | 14:15          | 0           | ...
14-05-18       | 19:15          | 0           | ...
15-05-18       | 12:25          | 0           | ...
```

__

Related with:

1. [Get last run date of task in Windows Scheduled Tasks from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565922/get-last-run-date-of-task-in-windows-scheduled-tasks-from-asp-net)